# How to use try and except inside a class in OOP in python

Tags: oop, error-handling, except

I am totally new to OOP in python. In the following code I wrote a class that computes the current age of a person by getting the birth date. The input data is a birth date like `1995/15/02`. I would like to handle the error if the user enter a month more than 12 or the day more than 31.

I aim to print the word `WRONG` in case the month or day is not in the expected domain. I tried the following code. But I get the `AttributeError` constantly.

How can I catch the error using `try` and `except` without facing the`AttributeError`.

Any help is really appreciated.

```
from datetime import date


class CurrentAge:

    def __init__(self):

        self.birth_date = input()           
        self.set_Birth_Date()

    def set_Birth_Date(self):

        year_month_day =[int(x) for x in self.birth_date.split("/")]

        """ month and day should be integers and hold the conditions 0 < month < 13
        0 < day < 32 """
        self.year = year_month_day[0]
        try:
            if 0 < year_month_day[1] and year_month_day[1]< 13:
                self.month = year_month_day[1]   
            else:
                raise TypeError("month must be between 1 and 12!")        
        except TypeError as exp:
            print("Wrong")     
        try:
            if 0 < year_month_day[2] and year_month_day[2] < 32: 
                self.day = year_month_day[2]     
            else: 
                raise TypeError("day should be between 1 and 31!")
        except:
            print("Wrong")

    def get_age(self):  
        self.current_year = date.today().year
        self.current_month = date.today().month
        self.current_day = date.today().day
        self.current_age = self.current_year - self.year

        if self.current_month < self.month:
            self.current_age-=1
        elif self.current_month == self.month and self.current_day < self.day:

            self.current_age-=1
        return(self.current_age) 

A = CurrentAge()
print(A.get_age())
```

Comment: Have you tried entering the birth date as a string, eg. '2000/04/29'? (There are other problems with this code, but they are outside the scope of this question; for example, taking an input as part of the constructor).

Comment: Yes, I tried to enter the input as a string.